# Very slow removing command buttons and rows from sheet

Tags: performance, vba, excel

This sub removes all command buttons and their associated rows that were created programmatically on a sheet. It takes around 20 seconds to remove 60 command buttons and rows. I've stepped through it and can find no problems with it.

```
Sub ResetForm_Click()

    Dim Contr
    Dim controlname As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = ActiveSheet

        For Each Contr In WS.OLEObjects

        controlname = Mid(Contr.Name, 1, 2)

            If controlname = "CB" Then
                Contr.TopLeftCell.Rows.EntireRow.Delete
                Contr.Delete
            End If

        Next

End Sub
```

Comment: First try turning off screenupdating and see if that improves things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of deleting rows one-by-one try something like this (untested):

```
Sub ResetForm_Click()

    Dim Contr
    Dim controlname As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet, rDel As Range

    Set WS = ActiveSheet

        For Each Contr In WS.OLEObjects

        controlname = Mid(Contr.Name, 1, 2)

            If controlname = "CB" Then
                If rDel Is Nothing then
                    Set rDel = Contr.TopLeftCell
                Else
                    Set rDel = Application.Union(rDel, Contr.TopLeftCell)
                End If 
                Contr.Delete
            End If

        Next

        If Not rDel Is Nothing then rDel.EntireRow.Delete 

End Sub
```

Comment: If he turns off screen updating and calculation too, that'd be super fast.

Answer (score 1):

Without editing your macro too much, turn off screen updating and autocalculation, see if that helps.

At the beginning of your macro (I usually put it after my declarations), add

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Then at the end (before `End Sub`), turn them back on

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```